# Error in Import CSV files

Tags: magento-1.9, import

I tried to import a csv file  to magento using `system->import/export->Dataflow Profiles`. But when importing that file getting an error like  **Could not load file:** `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/intow/var/import/pcpitems.csv`
[image]

Comment: but It gives some error when giving  chmod -R 777 /var permission

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my first comment It should be `chmod -R 777 var`

Comment: when giving  `chmod  -R 777 var` permission  it gives error like `chmod: Unable to change file mode on var/import: Operation not permitted`

Comment: What if you run `sudo chmod -R 777 var` ? Do you have access to a superuser account ?

Comment: yes. Its working when using  `sudo chmod -R 777 var` permission...But not able to import files

Comment: Instead of blindly running `sudo chmod`, please check what permission your file `/var/import/pcpitems.csv` actually has when this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing some steps in this process. Following are the urls which will help you to solve the problem.

1) http://coolblueweb.com/blog/importing-products-with-dataflow-profiles-the-basics/

2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAzcZprsOWE

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks.. But I want to import csv of a non magento database...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It happens that the csv file had a starting utf-8 char, so that's why didn't load the file.

The way I've solved this: try to edit manually csv file with an editor like Notepad++ and delete and rewrite the first char of the first row.

Hope it helps you.